# hide and show in ng repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
    <tbody ng-repeat="T in sal ">
            <!--| filter:search:strict" >-->
             <tr id="tr{{T.id}}" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">

                 <td >

                  <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="K in datavalue">
    <div ng-show="(p.id == K.emp_id && T.id == K.component_id)" ng-init="hideinputbox(T.id)">
       {{K.amount}}
    </div>

</div> 
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter valueg"  class="form-control" name="cvalue" id="{{T.id}}"  ng-model="T.cvalue"  required/>

 </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </form>
```

inside controller,

```
$scope.hideinputbox = function (k) { 

      $("input#k").hide();
     }
```

My issue is to hide the input box if the expression is true. 
If I give the id manually it is hiding the input box, but inside the loop it isn't working. I believe this line's causing the issue:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter valueg"  class="form-control" name="cvalue" id="{{T.id}}"  ng-model="T.cvalue"  required/>
```

Comment: Try not using Jquery together with Angular Js .It is a bad practise .

Answer (score 3):

Your function is wrong.You always call the function with the **string** *k* not with *k* **variable**. Change your code like this:

```
$scope.hideinputbox = function (k) { 

      $("input#" + k).hide();
     }
```

And as said @katmanco, don't use jQuery with AngularJS.

But why are you hiding your elements and also have **ng-show** ?

```
<div ng-show="(p.id == K.emp_id && T.id == K.component_id)" ng-init="hideinputbox(T.id)">
       {{K.amount}}
    </div>
```

If your `ng-show="condition"` is false it will be hiden, So I think you don't need the function